# Does Holdem Manager 2 have built in hand convertor?

Tags: texas-hold-em, software

Does Holdem Manger 2 have built in hand convertor for posting on forums or I can only copy hand to some online covertor? Also is there some hand convertor that I can download that works with Pokerstars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold'em Manager 2 has built-in capability for outputting to several common forum formats.

From the reports tab, right-click and select view. Then choose the format you want in the dropdown near the bottom right (which probably says "HM2 (Default)" to start out). Then click the "Copy To Clipboard" button and voila: you are ready to paste the hand history into the forum of your choice.